# How can I find defect cycle time using the VersionOne Core API?

Tags: versionone

I want to analyze the cycle time for defects. For each defect, across all iterations, I need to subtract the resolution date (the date the defect was closed) from the opening date (the date the defect was planned into an iteration). I am unable to find this among the available reports. How can I find defect cycle time using the VersionOne Core API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a predefined [attribute](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Concepts/Attribute) for cycle time. Rather, the value must be calculated using the [attribute definition syntax](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Attribute_Definition_Syntax). We use the `History` attribute, filtered by the range of statuses that make up the cycle, and sum up the days.

```
History[Status.Name='Future','In Progress','Done'].Days.@Sum
```

You can use the [query.v1 endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) to POST the following query:

```
from: Defect
where:
  Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name: The Desired Project
select:
  - Name
  - Status
  - History[Status.Name='Future','In Progress','Done'].Days.@Sum
```

Or, using the [rest-1.v1/Data endpoint](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData), you can GET the following query:

```
<Server Base URI>/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?where=Scope.ParentMeAndUp.Name='The%20Desired%20Project'&sel=Name,Status,History[Status.Name='Future','In%20Progress','Done'].Days.@Sum
```

Comment: My V1 installation doesn't support "History". I guess it's too old or something. Which version introduced this attribute?

Comment: I believe History was put in around 12.3.5.45